# Azure AD B2C - Using Azure AD Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am calling the Azure AD Graph API using a local administrator token. I keep getting the following error messages, no matter what endpoint I call.

How do I get access to the Azure AD Graph API?

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
    }
  }
}
```

My URL

```
 https://graph.windows.net/>tenant>/users/821d91b8-36e1-4b89-bd3a-4caecc40e4c9/memberOf?api-version=1.6
```

Comment: solved it. I cannot get access to graph API using an normal app. I have to follow this guide and create a "special graph API app" https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/

Comment: You should post this as an answer to your question rather than a comment and flag your question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Graph API needs a special application registration alongside the application registration that users log in with.

Follow the guide below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/

Comment: Why dont these 'special' apps show up on the Azure AD B2C Portal?

Comment: Absolutely no idea´:-)

Comment: What you are referring to as "special" are v1 Azure AD Apps whereas B2C works with (and shows) v2 Azure AD apps